# Unable to Focus Anything other than TextField

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-tv, android-jetpack-compose-canvas, android-jetpack-compose-tv

I have already viewed other posts on the site. They suggest using the `focusRequestor` modifier and I've tried that.

```
val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }
Text(
    modifier = Modifier
        .focusable()
        .focusTarget() //Tried Adding/Removing
        .onFocusChanged {
            if (it.hasFocus || it.isFocused) {
                Log.i("Test", "Text Focused")
            }
        } // Tried Adding Visual Elements to delete it as well.
        .focusRequester(focusRequester),
    text = "MARSK"
)

LaunchedEffect(scope) {
    focusRequester.requestFocus()
}
```

I'm taking `Text` in this example,  but actually I need to implement this on `Canvas`. This approach is not working on `Box` too. I'm afraid the same is the case for other containers as well.

For background, this is being built for my TV, so I wish to make this element clickable by the OK button on the remote's D-Pad. My approach is to make it focused first, then assuming that once it is focused, it will automatically detect the press of the OK button as the 'click'. If there is something wrong with my approach, feedback for improvements is also welcome.

PS: The solution by Abhimanyu works like a charm on Mobile Devices. However, since I mentioned a TV above, a TV is the device in consideration. On the TV, I have to press a button (Any button on the DPAD works, even the OK button, strangely) to get it focused up. Any idea how to get round this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Issue**
The `onFocusChanged` should be added BEFORE the `focusTarget` or `focusable` that is being observed.

[Source](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/focus/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).focusTarget())

**Changes**

1. Remove `focusTarget` and move `onFocusChanged` before `focusable`.
2. Also, note that `focusRequester` must be before `focusable`.

This would hopefully work for all comopsables. I have tested using `Text` and the example from Docs was using `Box`.

**Extra details**.

1. Prefer `focusable` over `focusTarget`.

   From `focusTarget` docs,

> Note: This is a low level modifier. Before using this consider using Modifier.focusable(). It uses a focusTarget in its implementation. Modifier.focusable() adds semantics that are needed for accessibility.

2. Order of Modifiers matter
   [Layouts in Jetpack Compose Codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-layouts#8)
   Check `Order Matters` section

> order matters when chaining modifiers as they're applied to the composable they modify from earlier to later,

**Sample code**

```
@Composable
fun FocusableText() {
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }
    var color by remember { mutableStateOf(White) }
    LaunchedEffect(scope) {
        focusRequester.requestFocus()
    }
    Text(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(color)
            .onFocusChanged {
                color = if (it.hasFocus || it.isFocused) {
                    LightGray
                } else {
                    White
                }
            }
            .focusRequester(focusRequester)
            .focusable(),
        text = "Test Text"
    )
}
```

The `Text` background is `LightGray` which indicates the text is focused.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Wow. I knew the order of the Modifiers mattered and interestingly that was the very reason for adding the `focusChanged` Modifier AFTER the `focusable` modifier. I thought that the Composable would need to be focusable in the first place in order for the focusChange to be detected at all. I know it's not that simple. You got an explanation for exactly why this works? Thanks! I'll accept it anyway since it works but I'll just see for a couple of hours if anyone gets an explanation for the behaviour.